# Redirect to admin page after login using admin status

Tags: php, authentication

I'm trying to get my code to login into a admin page if you log in as an admin using admin_status.

The connection is fine.

When I log in as an admin it takes me to home.php.

```
<?php  
    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {

    include 'connection.php';

    $username = $_POST['usernamey'];
    $password = $_POST['passwordy'];
    $check = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'") or die('lol');

    if (mysqli_num_rows($check) == 1){

        $array = mysqli_fetch_array($check);

    # LOGIN
    $_SESSION['userid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['ueradm'] = $array[0]['admin_status'];

    if($array[0]['admin_status'] === 1){
       header('location: admin.php');
    } else {
        header('location: home.php');
    }

    } else {
        echo "No Login";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check what `var_dump($array)` gives You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `if($array[0]['admin_status'] === 1){` to `if($array[0]['admin_status'] == 1){`

Answer (score 0):

Check if $array[0]['admin_status'] is not string by accident.